# 'id' not defined when referencing JSON object in NodeJs endpoint

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I am new to Javascript and have been following along with a course on NodeJs and am stuck on an exercise.

I am creating a basic CRUD API for 'genres' in a made up video store.

I have created all of the above but when I call any of the endpoint with a specific id I get an error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at genres.find.g (/Users/richardcurteis/Desktop/NodeJsCourse/vidly-node/index.js:60:65)
    at Array.find (native)
    at findGenre (/Users/richardcurteis/Desktop/NodeJsCourse/vidly-node/index.js:60:26)
```

The issue is (I think) related to the `findGenre` method which checks to see if a genre with the matching id exists.

```
function findGenre(req) {
    const genre = genres.find(g => g.id === parseInt(req.params.id));
    if(genre) return genre;
    false;
}
```

The `json` object is currently hardcoded.

This is the request (sent from Postman):

```
GET > http://localhost:5000/api/genres/1
```

This returns:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Action"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Horror"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Drama"
    }
]
```

I have checked against the solution and it appears to be the same implementation as mine, save for my refactoring repetitive checks and error codes.

Maybe I'm just going code blind, but maybe someone can see what I'm missing?

I have included the entire class (?) but like I said the error is related to the checking of the json objects id.

```
const Joi = require('joi');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

const genres = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Action' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Horror' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Drama' },
];

app.get('/api/genres', (req, res) => {
    res.send(genres);
});

app.post('/api/genres', (req, res) => {
    const { error } = validateGenreName(req.body);
    if(error) return sendValidationError(res, error);

    const genre = {
        id: genres.length + 1,
        name: req.body.name
    };
    genres.push(genre);
    res.send(genre);
});

app.put('/api/genres/:id', (res, req) => {
    const genre = findGenre(req);
    if(!genre) return genreNotFoundError(res);

    const { error } = validateGenreName(req.body);
    if(error) return sendValidationError(res, error);

    genre.name = req.body.name;
    res.send(genre);
});

app.delete('/api/genres/:id', (res, req) => {
    const genre = findGenre(req);
    if(!genre) genreNotFoundError(res);

    const index = genres.indexOf(genre);
    genres.splice(index, 1);

    res.send(genre);
});

app.get('/api/genres/:id', (res, req) => {
    const genre = findGenre(req);
    if(!genre) return genreNotFoundError(res);
    res.send(genre);
});


// Functions

function findGenre(req) {
    const genre = genres.find(g => g.id === parseInt(req.params.id));
    if(genre) return genre;
    false;
}

function genreNotFoundError(res) {
    res.status(404).send('Genre not found');
}

function validateGenreName(genre) {
    const schema = {
        name: Joi.string().min(3).required()
    };
    return Joi.validate(genre, schema);
}

function sendValidationError(res, error) {
    res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: What does the HTTP request look like? Clearly `:id` is undefined.

Comment: All elements in `genres` have an `id` property so it must be `req.params.id` that is the problem.

Comment: I've added it in, but: `GET http://localhost:5000/api/genres/1`

Comment: The problem is that one of the objects within the array `genres` is undefined.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "json object". It's a JavaScript object. JSON is a serialization format.

Comment: This `const index = genres.indexOf(genre);` is not ok, use `findIndex` instead.

Comment: @Ele, what is wrong with it?

Comment: @RichC There's nothing wrong with `.indexOf()`

Comment: indexOf is comparing same values in memory, of course, with your sample data will work, however, using real data (from db, file, Etc), that function probably will return -1 all the time.

Comment: @ralphtheninja you know is not ok indexOf for searching key-value pairs objects.

Comment: Try to find this: `genres.indexOf({ id: 1, name: 'Action' })` `<-----` will return `-1`

Comment: @Ele Maybe so. However, had nothing to do with the problem in this question.

Comment: Of course not, I'm telling him to be careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I see your problem. You have flipped `(req, res)` for the `.get` handler.

```
app.get('/api/genres/:id', (res, req) => {
    const genre = findGenre(req);
    if(!genre) return genreNotFoundError(res);
    res.send(genre);
});
```

Should be

```
app.get('/api/genres/:id', (req, res) => {
    const genre = findGenre(req);
    if(!genre) return genreNotFoundError(res);
    res.send(genre);
});
```

The same goes for `.delete` and `.put`.

Comment: That did it. I was code blind after all! Cheers dude

Comment: Nice catch. These kinds of mistakes can be maddeningly prone to avoiding quick detection 

Comment: @ChrisYeager, yeah that's two hours I won't get back in my life. Beer time